# Collect all connected devices on linux

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, linux

I'm trying to write a component that collects data about connected / attached devices.

My component should work on Linux as well as on Windows.
For the time being I succeeded doing that on Windows machines by querying the Win32_PnPEntity.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically collect data about all attached devices (I.e usb devices, disks, Bluetooth etc...) on Linux.

After searching the internet, 
I didn't found any solution to get all of this information.

As I said, in windows I can query the Win32_pnpentity,
Is there a way to do the same in Linux?
(I rather not use utilities, such as lshw etc...)

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: You can either use libusb to get a crossplatform interface that works equally well on Windows and Linux, or go fishing in `/sys/bus/usb`.

Comment: There’s no single call for that. To learn deeper, look at sources of **lshw** tool.

Answer (score -1):

libusb offers [examples/listdevs.c](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/listdevs.c), and this code should run equally well on Windows and Linux.

Alternatively, you can simply poke around in `/sys/bus/usb/devices`. For example, entries like `1-2`, `1-4`, (a digit, a dash, and a digit) represent whole connected devices, and these directories contain `manufacturer` and `product` files representing the device.

I'd use the libusb approach for anything I wanted to distribute widely. If you're doing internally-owned code then the directory approach should work well. Changes to the interface should be few and far between.